# ¿De dónde ha venido la «bofia»?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos

El [diccionario de la Real Academia Española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5kwg7Na) dice que es de origen desconocido:

> **bofia**
>   De or. desc.
>   f. jerg. **policía** (ǁ cuerpo de seguridad).

¿Cuándo y dónde fue la palabra registrada por primera vez? ¿En qué países se usa corrientemente?

La palabra existe también en portugués (*bófia*) y su origen es también desconocido, y creo que es muy reciente. Es posible que venga del castellano o que la palabra castellana venga del portugués. He preguntado la [misma cuestión en Portuguese SE](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/donde-%C3%A9-que-veio-a-b%C3%B3fia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el [CORDE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/corde), la primera aparición de la palabra en un texto con el significado que mencionas, es el siguiente:

> *- ¿Y llevaba dinero encima?*
>   *- Siempre. Dinero y alhajas; llevaba sobre su persona un capital. Pero no vayas a sospechar de mi novio. Es muy chulo, pero muy decente. No sé por qué me figuro que tú eres de la **bofia**.*
>
> Emilio Carrere, "La torre de los siete jorobados", circa 1923 (España).

La siguiente aparición es en 1951:

> *Cuando vienen los guardias, para que no las lleven detenidas, corren y se avisan unas a otras. Así, que no es raro ver de pronto doce o quince mujeres, corriendo y metiéndose en los portales, porque viene "la **bofia**".*
>
> Arturo Barea, "La forja de un rebelde", 1951 (España).

Como ves, ambos resultados son de España, donde sí se entiende la palabra. Ignoro si se usa o entiende en Hispanoamérica. Según el CREA, de 21 apariciones de la palabra en textos en los últimos 25 años, 20 son de textos españoles y 1 en un texto argentino.

Lo que no he podido encontrar es la etimología, la explicación de por qué se usa "bofia" para "policía".

He continuado la búsqueda en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España, y me salen ocurrencias de allá por 1920: "[un *bofia* es un policía](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000711233&page=4&search=bofia&lang=es)". También he encontrado [este otro texto](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0005049681&page=19&search=bofia&lang=es):

> Los ladrones dan actualmente el nombre
>   de "bofia" a la Policía, su "Enemigo malo"
>   de siempre.
>   El caló usado en cárceles y presidios,
>   como los idiomas y los dialectos, evoluciona y se renueva constantemente; así es que la Policía y polizontes se han ido transformando
>   en el léxico privativo del hampa, quien primero les llamó "la polilla"; después, "la carga" y "los cargueros"; más
>   tarde, "la jarea", y ahora -como ya hemos dicho- "la bofia".

Comment: Todo lo que yo quería saber, gracias. Curiosamente la [primera](https://books.google.pt/books?id=GiceAQAAIAAJ&q=b%C3%B3fia&dq=b%C3%B3fia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4idnlwu_QAhWGDpAKHRPvBNE4ZBDoAQi2ATAZ) y la [secunda ocurrencia de la palabra portuguesa *bófia* en Google Books](https://books.google.pt/books?id=j9FPAAAAMAAJ&q=b%C3%B3fia&dq=b%C3%B3fia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4idnlwu_QAhWGDpAKHRPvBNE4ZBDoAQibATAV) es en Brasil (1947, 1948), pero hoy nos es usada allá. La segunda sugiere posibles orígenes.